# dirname in case of class inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance, dirname

I've got a parent class which holds a common variable for a image path and which is set through the class constructor

```
abstract class Parent_Class {
     protected $image_path;

     public function __construct($image_path_base) {
         $this->image_path = $image_path_base . '/images/';         
    }
}
```

The base path depends on the child classes or rather their file locations.

```
class ChildA_Class {
    public function __construct() {
         parent::__construct(dirname(__FILE__));         
         ...
    }
}

class ChildB_Class {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(dirname(__FILE__));
        ...         
    }
}
```

Is there a way to eliminate the `dirname(__FILE__)` in the child classes and move the logic towards the parent class?

Comment: Don't hardcode the path, but pass it as parameter

Comment: As `parent::__construct(dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/')` in a child class?

Comment: It would be possible with Reflection, but I won't recommend it. Setting an image path based on the location of class files just seems wrong. Don't you separate code and other resources?

Comment: Mmm, I am not quite sure. My code is for a wordpress plugin, the classes are used for custom post types. The base class resides in its own folder. Then I've got some different "packages", which use it from their own location. The image_path is used to determine the location for the post-type icons (base icon, hover state, big icon).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do seems strange to me, but here is one possible solution to your problem using reflection and late static binding.

```
abstract class ParentClass
{
    protected $imagePath;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // get reflection for the current class
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass(get_called_class());

        // get the filename where the class was defined
        $definitionPath = $reflection->getFileName();

        // set the class image path
        $this->imagePath = realpath(dirname($definitionPath) . "/images/");
    }
}
```

Every child class would automatically have an image path based on where the child class was defined.